# How do I automatically delete all my emails on Gmail? (Android)

Tags: gmail

I recently made a Gmail account and shared it with my dad. I am worried he will ban me from having Gmail if he sees my emails (They are NOT bad)
How to delete emails as soon as I get them?
Please help!

Comment: How are you planning on seeing your emails, if they delete right away?

Comment: See if this helps http://www.businessinsider.com/automatically-delete-unwanted-gmail-2014-1 (you can open Gmail in desktop view in a browser)

Comment: Create a filter rule to delete the specific emails that match criteria when coming to your inbox. You can set "To" so you put your email. You can also set "has the words" so you can fine tune the filter. When a message arrives that matches your filter's criteria, you can choose the option to delete, skip the inbox (archive it), etc.